# What person is "this one"?

Tags: grammar

Some fantasy and science fiction novels have characters who do not like personal pronouns; they use constructions like "This one is eager to attend" rather than "I am eager to attend". What person is that considered? Is it still first, or does that make it third?

Comment: I always found that construction awkward; it seems like someone who learned English as a second language and still has some vestigial solecisms. That, or if used by a native speaker, extremely, cartoonishly affected. And it would be "talking about oneself in the third person".

Comment: Third person.  Remember "referring to oneself in the third person" ?

Comment: One has to be royalty to get away with _one_.

Comment: @DanBron Yeah, often that's the point: to show that it's an alien mindset or a translation problem or what not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be called **Illeism** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illeism) which is a device that refers to a *first person*  as a *third person*.
Julius Caesar is well known to have used this device in his writing on the Gallic Wars, and Shakespeare  continued to do so in his play *Julius Caesar* [Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-Julius-Caesar-why-does-Caesar-refer-to-himself-in-third-person).

In English, such reference will be grammatically in the *third person*.

This device is used more than some of us might imagine. For example:

> Bill does not care to wash windows.

When asked to wash windows he might say:

> Bill doesn't do windows.

It can be a useful device, if used sparingly.